# Как применить jQuery селектор к переменной

Tags: jquery

Извиняюсь за вопрос, с jQuery знаком всего 2 дня.

Мне надо из переменной, содержащей html разметку вытащить кусочек.

Что-то типа

result = result.$("#view-all");

Как это можно сделать? Можно ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const htmlString = "<div>...<span id='view-all'>test</span></div>";
const r = $(htmlString).find("#view-all");
console.log(r.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо за подсказук! но в моем случае решение оказалось немного другим:  
`final = $(res).ready().find("#view-all").html();`

.html() вместо .text();